# Query to list all partitions in Datomic

Tags: database, clojure, datomic

What is a query to list all partitions of a Datomic database?

This should return

```
[[:db.part/db] [:db.part/tx] [:db.part/user] .... ]
```

where `....` is all of the user defined partitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to get a list of all partitions in the database by searching for all entities associated with the `:db.part/db` entity via the `:db.install/partition` attribute:

```
(ns myns
  (:require [datomic.api :as d]))

(defn get-partitions [db]
  (d/q '[:find ?ident :where [:db.part/db :db.install/partition ?p]
                             [?p :db/ident ?ident]]
       db))
```

**Note**

The current version of Datomic (build 0.8.3524) has a shortcoming such that `:db.part/tx` and `:db.part/user` (two of the three built-in partitions) are treated specially and aren't actually associated with `:db.part/db` via `:db.install/partition`, so the result of the above query function won't include the two.

This problem [is going to be addressed](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/datomic/9xxoWH6RxhA/discussion) in one of the future builds of Datomic. In the meantime, you should take care of including `:db.part/tx` and `:db.part/user` in the result set yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**1st method - using query**

```
=> (q '[:find ?i :where 
       [:db.part/db :db.install/partition ?p] [?p :db/ident ?i]]
     (db conn))
```

**2nd method - from db object**

```
(filter #(instance? datomic.db.Partition %) (:elements (db conn)))
```

The second method returns sequence of *datomic.db.Partition* objects which may be useful if we want to get additional info about the partition.

Both methods have known bug/inconsistency: they don't return :db.part/tx and :db.part/user built-in partitions.